# How to add comment in closedXML when we have the columns which is calculated by the database data?

Tags: c#, datatable, closedxml

I want to export excel:
Expected result:

```
| Kira | mita| hakita|
|:---- |:----:| ----:|
| one  | two| Three  |
```

Kira is fixed column.

```
Mita and hakita can change when we calculate data. For example: it can have two column: mita1 and mita2 ......
```

I want to add comment for mita or hakita to export comment for my excel same expect result.
Now, I use datatable to define mita and hakita to add XLworkbook but I don't know use datatable to add comment to export excel. Help Me.

Comment: Can you give an example comment and how it should look in the exported excel?  Not sure what exactly the expected result should be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to add some comments to your generated Excel file.

```cs
// using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
var app = new Application();
var wb = app.Workbooks.Add();
var sheet = (Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;
((Range)sheet.Cells[1, 1]).Value = "My cell";
var comment = ((Range)sheet.Cells[1, 1]).AddComment("Your comment");
comment.Visible = true;
wb.SaveAs(@"yourPath\yourFile.xlsx");
wb.Close();
```

Comment: question was for closedxml

Answer (score 2):

Given that the question was about ClosedXML, here is a solution for that:

```
int currentRow = 1;
int currentCol = 1;
string myComment = "This is a comment";
Worksheet.Cell(currentRow, currentCol).Comment.AddText(myComment);
```